# Dynamic SQL with Dynamic Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write dynamic SQL that can accept up to 50 parameters. It can be 1 or 10 or 15. The limit is 50 from the main sproc but the input to the dynamic sql is not defined.

I have created this dynamic statement through a while loop. It will read the number of parameter in a table(3 in this example) and generates the statement below. I am not concerned with the performance of the while loop because the tables/input are very small:

```
--generated from while loop
DECLARE @rParam1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @rParam2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @rParam3 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @rParam1= Parameter_Name FROM [Template_Params] WHERE Key=12345 AND Sort_Order=1
SELECT @rParam2= Parameter_Name FROM [Template_Params] WHERE Key=12345 AND  Sort_Order=2
SELECT @rParam3= Parameter_Name FROM [Template_Params] WHERE Key=12345 AND Sort_Order=3
DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @BODY = Body FROM [Template] WHERE Key=12345
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam1,@PARAM_Input1)
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam2,@PARAM_Input2)
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam3,@PARAM_Input3)
SELECT @BODY
```

This so far works good.

The stored procedure can have 50 inputs but for example I will limit to 5 (only used 3)

```
--this is from the main sproc 
DECLARE @PARAM_Input1 NVARCHAR(MAX)='test',
@PARAM_Input2 NVARCHAR(MAX)='test1',
@PARAM_Input3 NVARCHAR(MAX)='test2',
@PARAM_Input4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
@PARAM_Input5 NVARCHAR(MAX),
@param_input6 nvarchar(max)
```

Now I need to get these values into the dynamic SQL so my final Dynamic statement should have

```
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam1,'test')
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam2,'test1')
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,@rparam3,'test2')
```

This is where I am stuck, I do not want to write the REPLACE Statement 50 times like this.

`SET @SQL=REPLACE(@SQL,'@PARAM_Input1',''''+@PARAM_Input1+'''')`

I tried a cursor but the name of the variable has to be dynamic and it's not in the same scope so the values from the sproc are not being passed.

Comment: That looks like inviting [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are good references for what you are trying to do: [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
 - [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Rather than passing 50 separate values into your SP, have you thought about using a @variable table. It could be less messy, and allow you to build your dynamic code with a structure like a Recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be possible in SQL to do what you have in mind. A solution could be if you can send a table as parameter to contain the information as below (or generate it dinamically:

```
ParameterName            | Value
<value of @rParam1>      | <value of @Param_Input1>
<value of @rParam2>      | <value of @PARAM_Input2>
```

Then, update `@BODY` variable

```
SELECT @BODY = Body FROM [Template] WHERE Key=12345
UPDATE <TableParameter_Or_Variable>
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body, ParameterName, Value)
```

I don't know how you obtain the values for `@PARAM_InputX`, but for `@rParamX' you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO @Table 
SELECT Parameter_Name AS ParameterName, null AS Value
[Template_Params] WHERE Key=12345
ORDER BY sort_order
```

and then update the rows accordingly. On `@Table` you can open a cursor and match the current row to `@PARAM_InputX`.